# Issue with xsl-fo :footnote when generating pdf/ua-1 document with fop.: "tagged PDF note id is missing"

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop, tagged-pdf

I have an issue with <fo:footnote> when generating pdf/ua-1 document with fop.
The resulting pdf displays correctly the footnote in the page but don’t pass the pdf-ua validation. A severe error on pdf tag Note “id is missing” is raised so the document is not conformed. I'm using PAC3 for the conformance test.

In the example below I have extracted the basic <fo:footnote> element which has a unique id.
How can I generate the missing Id attribute in the pdf tagged Note element?

Here is the xsl-fo really simple footnote. Note that I used an id to reference the footnote.

```
some text...
<fo:footnote id="FNE0001">
  <fo:inline font-size="6pt" baseline-shift="super">E0001</fo:inline>
 <fo:footnote-body>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline>E0001</fo:inline><fo:inline > JO L 139 du 29.5.2002, p. 9.</fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:footnote-body>
</fo:footnote> some text...
```

Apache FOP has been set to generate pdf-ua through the conf file as follow:

```
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <!-- Before setting the pdf-ua-mode, we must insert metadata Title in FO declaration -->
      <pdf-ua-mode>PDF/UA-1</pdf-ua-mode>  
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

PAC3 is checking against the failure conditions in the Matterhorn Protocol; latest edition at https://www.pdfa.org/resource/the-matterhorn-protocol/.

PAC3 is probably reporting on failure condition 19-003, ID entry of the  tag is not present.

`fo:footnote-body` can have an `id` property. You could try adding an ID to that. In the `fo:inline` for the footnote marker, you might also need to add an `fo:basic-link` that refers to that ID.

FWIW, your footnote does not cause that error when checking PDF/UA generated by AH Formatter, and I'm only guessing at what FOP would be doing differently. (PAC3 and I generally disagree when it complains about a footnote being a possibly incorrect use of a Note tag, but that's another story: PAC3 tries to automate checking the conditions that should be checked by a human, and it doesn't always get it right.)

Comment: I added an ID at the `fo:footnote-body` and greated a fo:basic-link at the marker referencing that id. The error is still there and more the link is not working.
There is a workaround to bypass the error. Put a an attribute role="P" at the fo:footnote -)

Comment: `role="P'` means (I assume) that your footnote is no longer tagged as a Note. You've stopped one error message being shown, but you've caused another error that PAC3 isn't competent to find: 19-001, Footnotes or endnotes are not tagged as <Note>.

Comment: I agree with you. The "role=P" was a joke. To come back to this issue, I followed the guide  "Tagged PDF Best Practice Guide: Syntax" (pdf association and place the different elements in the strict order as their example. Including creating a role "Note" closer to the `fo:block`inside the foornote body. The Note as created and the logical tree showed that the generated structure mapped the example. But the error persisted. So I placed an ID in each elements of the structure, same issue. I don't get the problem. Is this an FOP issue? Or what? Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was a joke. Sorry, also, but if you've placed IDs everywhere that you can and it still persists, it does look like a FOP problem and not something that I could help you fix.

Comment: As a question, could you place the footnote  content in alt text to be read at the time it is encountered and then place the visual part in an artifact?